# How to access property set up using Context in SOAPUI in request parameters

Tags: soapui

I am fetching the id from the response and setting is as context.id parameter. I am not able to access the same in the subsequent request using ${id} or {context.id}

```
//Set the id property using context
context.id = jsonSlurper.data.id
```

Comment: Question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context` is a special case for property expansion.

In your follow requests you can use the follow notation, to acces the property:

```
${=context.id}
```